# how to integrate an android .aar library file into a flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, dependencies, aar, integrate

[image]

i already added a folder inside android directory called linklibrary and add .aar file and also include build.gradle file inside gradle I added

```
configurations.maybeCreate("default")

artifacts.add("default", file('E4link-1.0.0.aar'))
```

is there anyone know the steps of how to integrate .aar dependency to my flutter project and also
know how to use those library functions inside the flutter project.

I am new to flutter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a libs folder in android root folder then adding your `.aar` file to `libs`(in your case `liblibrary`) folder in android root folder, add this in android `build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs '../libs' // in your case liblibrary
        }
    }
}
```

then in app `build.gradle` add this:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation(name:'your_file_name', ext:'aar')
}
```

then sync your gradle and you are good to go.

Comment: thanks bro, i actually integrate it , but i don't know to how to communicate with that library from java to flutter , when clicking a button from flutter I want to call that library function from java , how to do that , is there any sample code?, can you please send me any sample code link. its urgent

Comment: You can fine a sample in this [link](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)

Comment: hi, the flutter official documentation only shows sample method channel example, there it passes only small values , how can I pass a value after an API call using the native java library ?